# PHP session not working on docker

Tags: php, session, docker, file-permissions

I am trying to set up a PHP application but something seems to be wrong with session handling.

[image: Here's my <code>php.ini</code> session settings (run fro container level)]

As you can see the configuration is quite standard. I checked the `/tmp` permissions from the container and got

```
root@2217e6d458ad:/# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 08:03 /tmp
```

I also checked in runtime following snippet:

```
$file = fopen('/tmp/foo.log', 'w');
fwrite($file, 'test'.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
echo 'path: '. session_save_path().'<br>';
var_dump(is_writable(session_save_path()));
```

Now, the file `/tmp/foo.log` was created, the `path` was empty but the `var_dump` results with `bool(false)`.

What else should I check??

Comment: Session save path has no value in the php config.

Comment: `session_save_path()` being blank means default to /tmp, BUT your check of `is_writable()` is checking blank and not `/tmp`

Comment: Can you give some code example to show how your session handling is failing

Comment: @NigelRen Actually after your first comment I prepared very simple snippet to check session and it seems to be working - the problem is somewhere on the application level...

Answer (score 0):

This case same with me and i did fixed that
and i used bitnami repository codeigniter image

you can add that command on dockerfile if u same with me

```
RUN echo "session.save_path=\"/tmp\"" >> /opt/bitnami/php/lib/php.ini
```

or can type on php container kernel terminal

```
#$ echo "session.save_path=\"/tmp\"" >> /opt/bitnami/php/lib/php.ini
```

*/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php.ini* is php configure file folder, you can check whereis php.ini file with running on the browser

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

you can check and  run my images on
https://hub.docker.com/r/ranur/codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using `wordpress:php7.4-fpm`) I also needed to set `session.auto_start = On` for sessions to start working, despite calling `session_start()` at the very top of every script like you're supposed to.